I get an error while building NEF board project
I downloaded the project from git as previously other developer was working. i did all the installations but when I am building the project I get this error:

[{
"resource": "/opt/nordic/ncs/v2.3.0/zephyr/include/zephyr/device.h",
"owner": "cpptools",
"severity": 8,
"message": "'__device_dts_ord_DT_N_ALIAS_doorfl_P_gpios_IDX_0_PH_ORD' undeclared here (not in a function)",
"source": "gcc",
"startLineNumber": 83,
"startColumn": 41,
"endLineNumber": 83,
"endColumn": 41
}]



[{
"resource": "/opt/nordic/ncs/v2.3.0/zephyr/include/zephyr/devicetree.h",
"owner": "cpptools",
"severity": 8,
"message": "'DT_N_ALIAS_doorfl_P_gpios_IDX_0_VAL_pin' undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean 'DT_N_S_leds_S_led_3_P_gpios_IDX_0_VAL_pin'?",
"source": "gcc",
"startLineNumber": 230,
"startColumn": 32,
"endLineNumber": 230,
"endColumn": 32
}]




I tried to use different version of the SDK, but the error is still there

This is a DTS error, which likely means that something is missing from the DTS.
A common reason for this is building for the wrong board.
Does the project you clone specify which boards it is supports?

Yes, you were right. after selecting the right board it was able to build
